# Filter nested arrays with objects

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array of Categories. Each Category instance has offers property.

```
class Category {
   var offers : [Offer]?
   var title : String?
   var id : Int?
}

class Offer {
    var type : String?
}

//global variable
var categories = [ categ1, categ2, ...]
```

How can I filter categories by offer.type ?

I already have tried:

```
return categories.map { (category) -> Category in
    let offers = category.offers?.filter { $0.type == myType }
    category.offers = offers
    return category
}
```

It works but after calling function second time array becomes empty. Probably because offers were rewritten?

Then I have tried this (produced same wrong result):

```
var resultCategories = [Category]()

for category in categories {
    guard let offers = category.offers else { continue }

    var newOffers = [Offer]()

    for offer in offers {
        if offer.type == myType {
            newOffers.append(offer)
        }
    }

    category.offers = newOffers
    resultCategories.append(category)
}

return resultCategories
```

Comment: You're right, you're probably getting an empty array the second time because you're overwriting the offers after filtering them on the type. If you just want to filter on the basis of type then follow iParesh's answer below.

Comment: But how can I do filter without missing original data, for another filterings (for example: uisegmented control filters rows in uitableview)?

Comment: Assign the result of the filter to a different variable and use that as your datasource. Don't modify original categories array. 
`let resultCategories = categories.filter { // Your filter logic } `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply `filter` all categories that have no offers equals to your type. You can achieve that by:

1. filter all your categories and
2. inside the `filter` check if current offers contains the `myType`

Code:

```
let filtered = categories.filter { category in
    category.offers?.contains(where: { $0.type == myType }) ?? false
}
```

And note, that `category.offers?.[...]` is optional value, so the `?? false` returns `false` as result if left part is `nil`.

---

UPD.

> But I expected that categories will have only offers with type = "A". Maybe I did not described the question accurately.

You can achieve that by creating a new `Category`.

```
let filtered = categories.compactMap { category -> Category? in
    guard let offers = category.offers?.filter({ $0.type == "A" }) else { return nil }
    let other = Category()
    other.offers = offers
    return other
}
```

Also note, i'm using `compactMap`. It allows me to filter categories with empty or nil `offers` out.

Comment: I just have checked answers in playground unfortunately both are wrong. https://gist.github.com/Asich/f86b19d2ed214eeb8b88ae23fadddbec

Comment: Hi, @Asike. You code correct and works as expected, because both categories have at least one offer with type "A". If you try to change the `offer3`'s type to "C", you'll see offers only from first category. Note, you filtering _categories_, not offers.

Comment: I've got you. But I expected that categories will have only offers with type = "A". And if an offer will not correspond to that rule then category will not be included into result array.  Maybe I did not described the question accurately.

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple and easy `filter`(functional programming) instead of `for-loop`.
First filter category then check offers contains particular type or not(using equal to condition)

```
let data = categories.filter { ($0.offers?.contains(where: {$0.type == "yourtype"})) ?? false
    }
```

Comment: This will crash when `offers` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple filter, like one field from one model and second field from nested array, please che

```
 let searchText = "a"
 let filteredCategoryList = list.filter { category in
     let categoryFilter = category.title?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
     let offerFilter = category.offers?.contains(where: { $0.type?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
     })

     return categoryFilter || offerFilter ?? false
 }
```