# Swift: Filter nested arrays

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I'm trying to filter an array of `Deals` with a status `DealStaus` which has a nested array of `Bookings`, each one with a `BookingStatus`.
I want to filter Deals with status `.won` and Bookings according to the statuses given when calling the function. `BookingStatus` and `DealStatus` are both enums.
`Deal` and `Booking` look like this:

```
public struct Deal: Decodable {
    public let identifier: String?
    public let status: DealStatus
    public let bookings: [Booking]?
}

public struct Booking: Decodable {
    public let identifier: String?
    public let status: BookingStatus
    public let startDate: Date?
    public let endDate: Date?
}
```

To do so I wrote the following snippet:

```
private func getDeals(with bookingStatus: [BookingStatus]) -> [Deal] {
    guard let user = currentUser, let deals = user.deals else { return [Deal]() } // Note: user is a class attribute

    return deals.filter { $0.status == .won && $0.bookings?.filter { bookingStatus.contains($0.status) }}

}
```

This does not work. The compiler gives the following error:

> Optional type '[Booking]?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!=
>   nil' instead

Comment: `$0.bookings?.filter { bookingStatus.contains($0.status) }` is an array. What is needed here is a Boolean, i,e, true or false.

Comment: You are trying to be too compact. Filter your Deals. Stop. Then, operating on that array of Deals, map to get a new array of Deals with their bookings filtered. Stop. Now return that new array.

Comment: Or create a function in `Deal` that does the check and returns a boolean so you could call `... && $0.checkBookings(bookingStatus)`

Comment: For more help, show code! Show definitions of Deal and DealStatus and Booking and BookingStatus.

Comment: I have added the definitions of `Deal` and `Booking`

Comment: I have added an answer. Do you thing I could put together both filters? (I don't know if it would improve performance or readability...)

Comment: Please check below answer.
With multiple filter
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54421564/2781720

Answer (score 5):

Following the instructions of @matt, I broke it down:

```
private func getDeals(with bookingStatus: [BookingStatus]) -> [Deal] {
    guard let user = currentUser, let deals = user.deals else { return [Deal]() }
        return deals
            .filter { $0.status == .won }
            .filter { $0.bookings?.contains(where: { bookingStatus.contains($0.status)} ) ?? false }
    }
```